# how to know IIS installed or not Programmatically

Tags: c#, iis

In a Windows form Application  how to know iis is installed in local machine using c# programmatically

Answer (score 7):

If the IIS is installed the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp` should exist and it should contain an entry `VersionString`.

Source: [here](https://help.upcurvecloud.com/wmobile/howto_verify_aspnet_installed.html)

---

```
private static bool IsIisInstalled() => Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp", "VersionString", null) != null;
```

Answer (score 4):

With regards to checking the registry key, I have found that if you have IIS installed and you uninstall it, it leaves the key in the registry. Hence that is not a reliable way to test for the presence of IIS.

I opted for checking if the IIS Windows service exists using the following code:

`IsIisInstalled = ServiceController.GetServices().Any(s => s.ServiceName.Equals("w3svc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));`